# How can I call a function when another have been executed

Tags: javascript, function, delayed-execution, asynchronous-javascript

I'm a complete beginner at JavaScript. I just want to call the function called seconONe() just after the function firstOne() completes its execution. by saying this, I mean the function two will call when the value of that p1 is 4 ( in this case ); I can achieve it by calling a setTimeout() function. but what if I don't know how many does it take to execute { the first one() }?

```
 // getting DOM element
const p1 = document.getElementById(`one`);
const p2 = document.getElementById(`two`);
const p3 = document.getElementById(`three`);

// first function
function firstOne() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            p1.innerHTML = i;
        }, i * 1000);
    }
}

// second function
function seconOne() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            p2.innerHTML = i;
        }, i * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Callbacks are your friend for this :) https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_callback.asp However, may I ask why you use setTimeout?

Comment: "What the heck is the event loop anyway? | Philip Roberts | JSConf EU" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: I just want create section where the value of an element increase in every second or more and less time!.  and just to make sure that user can see the increment I use time out function!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to work with **promises**. More info about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

*Working example*

```js
var p1 = 1;
var p2 = 2;
var p3 = 3;

const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            p1 = i;
        }, i * 1000);
    }
  resolve()
 
});

const secondPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            p2 = i;
        }, i * 1000);
    }
    resolve()
});


//run first promise
console.log("First promise called")
firstPromise
  .then((response) => {
    console.log("First promise done")
    
    //run second promise after first promise succeed
    console.log("Second promise called")
    secondPromise
      .then((response) => console.log("Second promise done"))
  })
```

Comment: You should update your snippet code so that it works.

Comment: As you wish @Andy

Answer (score 0):

your question is not childish at all. What you will need to understand are callbacks and promise handlers. This just tells JavaScript to wait till a task has been completed in order to execute the next task.

```
firstOne().then(() => secondOne())
```

Answer (score 0):

put if condition in your firstOne function.

```
const p1 = document.getElementById(`one`);
const p2 = document.getElementById(`two`);
const p3 = document.getElementById(`three`);

// first function
function firstOne() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if(i == 4){
               seconOne();
            }else{
                p1.innerHTML = i;
            }
        }, i * 1000);
    }
}

// second function
function seconOne() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            p2.innerHTML = i;
        }, i * 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to build on the other answers that have [suggested using a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), here's a more generalised solution that also uses [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

(In summary: call a function with a count, and an element. That function will return a promise that "at some point" work will be completed. An inner function loops updating the element content until that count has been reached, at which point the promise resolves, and the next thing can start).

```js
// Cache the elements
const p1 = document.querySelector('#one');
const p2 = document.querySelector('#two');
const p3 = document.querySelector('#three');

// `timer` accepts a count, and the element
// to apply the count to
function timer(count, el) {

  // Return a promise that basically says:
  // once I'm done doing this work, resolve,
  // and then the event queue can
  // get on with the next thing
  return new Promise(resolve => {

    // So we create a loop that logs the numbers
    // in our element up to the count we specified.
    // and when that number is reached, resolve the promise
    function loop(n = 0) {

      // If our current `n` value is <= count
      if (n <= count) {

        // Set the content of the element
        el.textContent = n;

        // Call `loop` again after a second
        // with an incremented `n` value
        setTimeout(loop, 1000, ++n);

      // Otherwise resolve the promise
      } else {
        resolve();
      }

    }

    loop();

  });
}

// And now we just await each resolved promise
async function main() {
  await timer(4, p1);
  await timer(7, p2);
  await timer(20, p3);
  console.log('Done!');
}

main();
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Additional documentation

- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)